# Zend Framework 2 + docker: MongoDB ConnectionTimeoutException

Tags: php, mongodb, docker, zend-framework2

I am using Zend Framework 2 and MongoDB v3.2.11.

When I start up my ZF app, get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set) in /var/www/project/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Collection.php on line 360

Here's my docker-compose:

```
mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.2.11
    restart: always
    container_name: mongodb
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/project
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mongopassword
    volumes:
      - mongodb-data:/data/project
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: mongod --smallfiles
```

Here's my ZF config:

```
'caches' => [
        'Project\Web\Cache\Sessions' => [
            'template' => 'mongodb',
            'adapter' => [
                'name' => 'Project\Common\Cache\Storage\Adapter\MongoDb',
                'options' => [
                    'server' => getenv('ZF_MONGO_HOST'),
                    'connection_options' => [
                        'connect' => true,
                        'connectTimeoutMS' => 5000,
                        'fsync' => true,
                        'readPreference' => 'primaryPreferred',
                        'replicaSet' => 'set-1',
                    ],
                    'database' => getenv('ZF_MONGO_DATABASE_NAME'),
                    'collection' => 'sessions',
                    'ttl' => 3600,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Here's my docker-compose.env:

```
## MONGO DB ##
ZF_MONGO_HOST=mongodb://my_user:mymongopassword@mongodb/my_db
ZF_MONGO_DATABASE_NAME=my_db
```

What I tried:
* When I connect to the mongodb, it works
* I tested the user credentials: works
* When I change the `ZF_MONGO_HOST` I get the same error but in the brackets I see that he cannot connect to the - wrong - url. So the setup seems ok.
* Googling for ~3h: All the errors are connected to offline mongodb servers...

Any ideas?

**Update**:

I tried out the bitnami image, following setup:

```
  mongodb:
    image: bitnami/mongodb:3.6.8
    restart: always
    container_name: mongodb
    environment:
      - MONGODB_USERNAME=my_user
      - MONGODB_PASSWORD=mymongopassword
      - MONGODB_DATABASE=my_db
    volumes:
      - mongodb-data:/data/db-bitnami
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After docker `docker-compose up`, connect to MongoDB database and type `rs.status()` and it should have `member` field which indicates it's the slave. if it's not set, you need to defind it in mongodb:

```
rs.initiate( {
   _id : "set-1",
   members: [
      { _id: 0, host: "mongodb0.example.net:27017" },
      { _id: 1, host: "mongodb1.example.net:27017" },
      { _id: 2, host: "mongodb2.example.net:27017" }
   ]
})
```

after this step your mongodb has been replicated and ready to use. for automating second part of this (config mongodb) you can write a bash script which work as `Entrypoint` in docker-compose file or use some replicated docker images like [bitnami](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/mongodb/).

Comment: Great! Some progress! I added 'localhost:27017', when I try to add 'mongodb:27017' as well (thats my network name in the docker-compose) I get an error. When I leave out 'mongodb' I get in php the error `connection refused calling ismaster on 'localhost:27017'`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ron you should specify replicaset name `MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=primary`

Comment: Ok, great. Now I get my "regular" error again: `ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable servers found ('serverSelectionTryOnce' set)`

Comment: @Ron I don't know about PHP but what is your MongoDB connection string in env?

Comment: `ZF_MONGO_HOST=mongodb://my_user:mymongopassword@mongodb:27017/my_db`

Comment: @Ron apparently `mongodb` host not defined well in the system, but you can connect it directly by ip address. get ip with `docker inspect mongodb | grep ip` and use it instead hostname.

Comment: Sorry, changes nothing... Really odd. Further ideas?